# Select multiple values from a column based on a certain value from another column

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have three mysql tables as "Courses", "Modules", and "Course_Managements" as following...

"Modules" Table...

```
Module_id   Module_title
  1         Accounting
  2         Management
  3         Marketing
```

"Courses" Table...

```
Course_id   Course_title
  1          CIMA
  2          aat
  3          SLIM
  4          MBA
```

"Course_Managements" Table...

```
 CM_id   Module_id  Course_id
  1           1         1
  2           1         2
  3           2         1
  4           2         4
  5           3         3
  6           3         4
```

I want to assign SQL Query, by selecting a Course ID (Let's say '1') then the available Module_ids have to be listed as... '1' and '2'

I'm trying to develop an interface by which a User can select a Course then he / she  can view the Modules under it...

Could anyone suggest a SQL Query to do it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take input of `courseId` from User and use following query to get `modules`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Modules
INNER JOIN Course_Managements ON Modules.Module_id = Course_Managements.Module_id
WHERE Course_Managements.Course_id = $course_id
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
select t2.Course_id,
t2.Course_title,
group_concat(t1.Module_title separator ',') as Modules
from modules t1
join courses t2
join course_management t3
on t1.Module_id=t3.Module_id
and t2.Course_id=t3.Course_id
where t2.Course_id=1
group by t2.Course_id,
t2.Course_title;
```

[Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1abcf/5)